# Creating a private repo for third party artifacts in nginx server

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository, fedora, yum

While deploying EC2 instances and instructing to have some pre installed packages to be setup by saltstack works fine, but at times due to network connectivity third party packages fails to be installs, so the whole setup fails.

dependencies like fedora project package, epel etc, so if i want to create a private repo in EC2 instances (nginx server) to keep the above mentioned artifacts, how can it been done?

It should act like a secondary repo if the initial primary repo fails. is it a feasible task?

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) to build an AMI with all of your packages already installed?

Comment: I think JFrog would be great for this purpose. You can setup a mirror repository.

Your EC2 server will be pointing to the JFrog instance. And Jfrog instance will be download and cache all needed packages. JFrog downloads package one time and then just give you a cached package. Even if main package repo will be unavailable, you still can install needed package

Comment: @Parsifal I've heard of it, but never used it, Thanks will check it out !

Comment: @vallgorr actually thought of using the JFrog but our Jfrog is on another network so we want to use the s3 bucket to store the packages (yum repo) and be consumed by instances. AWS isnt connect to our internal network now, Thanks!